# Calling simple count() on Spark dataframe fails

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

Cluster manager: YARN

Deploy-mode : None

I was told if deploy mode is set to none, stdout of drives process comes at the root path, instead of inside container id of the driver process.

SparkUI logs: Give error `Container executed on lost node...`

I have unpersisted all other dataframes/datasets before making this call to ensure, they are not cached in memory.

Calling a simple action like `count()`, keeps failing.

I am essentially doing the following:

```
columnNames.keys.foreach(
  col => {
    val nonNullColCount = 
      dataset.select(dataset(col)).filter(row => 
      row.getAs(col) != null).count()
    println(nonNullParamsCount)
  })
```

So, i am calling `count()` on dataset in a loop.
In each iteration, i select a column from a list of column names.

Errors are generic and misleading, in the form of:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 284 in stage 14.0 failed 4 times,
most recent failure: Lost task 284.3 in stage 14.0 (TID 100923, ip-172-31-50-226.ec2.internal, executor 266): 
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 266 exited caused by one of the running tasks) 
Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1506075842477_0672_01_017877 on host: ip-172-31-50-226.ec2.internal. 
Exit status: -100. 
Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node
```

Comment: Can you add Sprk UI logs , also add few more info like Spark version , mode (Cluster Yarn or Mesos ) ,standalone and full logs

Comment: edited info accordingly.

Comment: isyour configuration on AWS ?

Comment: yes. it is on aws emr.

Comment: are you using spot instance ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS spot instance and spot instance taken back of price change you can get following error.

> Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a lost node

Workaround split the Spark job into many independent steps, so you can save the 
 result of each step as a file on S3 in short interval or go with non spot instance.